# Bootstrap (and Angular) validation vs responsive conflict

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Imagine a simple a form consisting of two rows and two columns:

Title..............Password
First name....Repeat password

If each ‘row’ is wrapped up in a **div class=”row”**, a validation message appearing under Password correctly shifts downwards both fields in the second row – ‘First name’ and ‘Repeat password’. Everything is neatly aligned, great! However, if I shrink the screen to the size of a mobile device an incorrectly ordered single column is created:

Title

Password

First name

Repeat password

**Instead of:**

Title

First name

Password

Repeat password

However, if I instead have one row and place the ‘Title’ and ‘First name’ column form groups in one **div class="col-md-6"**, and the ‘Password’ and ‘Repeat password’ inside a second **div class="col-md-6"**, I get the correctly ordered single column on a small screen – which is great, but validation messages knock the row cells out of vertical alignment on a large screen i.e.

Title..............Password

First name...(Required)

....................Repeat password.

Any ideas on how to get both correct alignment and sensible responsiveness? I’ve included a plunk to illustrate. (View on full screen.)

http://plnkr.co/edit/MKiS8MMfnivtb8ZTqmuZ?p=preview

Many thanks in advance...

```
<HTML>
```